# IdentityServer4: should GetLogoutContextAsync return multiple SignOutIFrameUrls

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

While implementing a federated single logout (SLO) in our application using IdentityServer4, I was surprised to see only a single SignOutIFrameUrl property in a LogoutRequest object returned by GetLogoutContextAsync method.

Shouldn't it be a collection of iframe URLs for every registered client? We want to trigger a logout for all clients obviously, so we need to generate an iframe per client resulting in multiple iframes rendered on "logged out" page.

I may be missing something here, as [documentation mentions "clients"](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/signout.html#notifying-clients-that-the-user-has-signed-out) but then describes only a single SignOutIframeUrl property.

Answer (score 0):

IdentityServer keeps track of the clients that you have actually logged into and returns a list of `SignOutIFrameUrl` for *those* clients.  If you haven't visited a particular client after single log-on, then it won't be contacted for logout by design during single log out.

Just happened to be looking at this again in a project today and I forgot one detail.  The logged out page renders 1 iframe and the URL is the endsessioncallback endpoint, then the page in that iframe renders many iframes, one for each logged in client.  So you would not see the list version until you looked at the code to render the inner iframes.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Jim! So how can I get a list of SignOutIFrameUrl for those clients? That part specifically is not really clear to me.